# Debugging android app does not install on emulator or device

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, adb

I was having an issue with debugging my app with eclipse. When I go to debug on either a real device or on an emulator the process goes fine except on the console it gets stuck saying "app_name.apk installing....". There are no error messages and I even tried it with the standard hello world app. I've never had this issue before with my previous app, however I have updated the SDK since then. I have `debuggable = true`, and do have the  block in the manifest which is a common problem. I also set up the real device for unknown sources and debugging. I didn't know if anybody else had this problem and fixed it ? Maybe its an issue the ADB?

Comment: I can upload some more information in an hour or 2 if anybody needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work, uninstalled eclipse and the SDK and got the newest version from google. Previously eclipse wouldn't let me update the ADB and I'm assuming that's the root of the error. Works fine now and the new version of eclipse looks super classy.